# as3 textField vs label vs textArea

Tags: actionscript-3

What is the difference between TextField, Label, and TextArea in flash. I'm trying to find the most lightweight class to display text because I will be making lots of them. Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/text/TextField.html) is the base display object that Flash uses to display text, while [Label](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/fl/controls/Label.html) and [TextArea](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/fl/controls/TextArea.html) are UIComponents that support things like skinning and styling. If TextField does everything you need, generally that's what you should probably be using. (And if you're making lots of them, you might consider enabling [cacheAsBitmap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#cacheAsBitmap), to limit how often the text is rendered.)

Comment: you had me at cacheAsBitmap (which coincidentally happens to be at the end of your answer lol :P)

Answer (score 2):

`TextField` is the lowest level text component provided by the player itself.

`Label` is a wrapper that introduces the functionality provided by the Flash framework and provides read-only text component.

`TextArea` is a wrapper that introduces the functionality provided by the Flash framework and provides a read-write text component.

I wouldn't automatically use `TextField` in an application that is otherwise using the Flash framework just because you're making a lot of them.  If `Label` or `TextArea` provide functionality that is useful then use those.  If not, then stick with `TextField`.